# Apply the same SQL query to all partners [Odoo]

Tags: sql, postgresql, odoo

I want to add a tax to every single partner with a single query if it's possible. I have 4700 partners, so it's non-viable to do it query by query. I'm looking for a query that do this like if it's a loop function.

This is the Query that I already have. In this case only apply for partner with ID 9915 (And works OK).

```
INSERT INTO 
    res_partner_perception 
      (id, perception_id, create_date, percent,  excluded, partner_id) 
VALUES 
    ((SELECT COALESCE(MAX(id), 0) FROM res_partner_perception) + 1,114,
      now(),3,0,9915);
```

But i want to apply this query to ALL partner_ids that exists in the database. How can i do this?

Comment: **Add to your question** the following information. 1) Why are you doing an INSERT when you just want to add a tax value. 2)  Are the `percent` and `excluded` values constants. 3) If 2) is no then add an extended example across more then one `id`.

Comment: 1) The way of adding a tax in the system is creating a new value for res_partner_perception and linking selecting the partner by his ID. 2) are both variables, integers

Comment: Per previous request: 1) **Add information** as update to question not as a comment. 2) Also add example showing what you want to achieve for creating more then one new tax. In particular where you are getting the values for `percent` and `excluded` and how they map to `id`?

Comment: **a)** in the insert you specify 6 columns, but provide values for only 5, does not appear to be valid. **b)** is `perception_id` a foreign key? **c)** are `percent,` & `excluded` always 3 & 0 respectively?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that there is a table `all_partner_ids` in your database you could do a query like this:

```
INSERT INTO res_partner_perception 
          (id, perception_id, create_date, percent,  excluded, partner_id) 
    SELECT
        (SELECT COALESCE(MAX(id), 0) FROM res_partner_perception) + row_number() over(),
            114,
            now(),
            3,
            0,
            p.id
    FROM all_partner_ids p;
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I changed the table name with res_partner and worked perfectly.